# i can't do makemigrations in django 1.11 (fields.E312)

Tags: python-3.6, django-1.11

class Player(models.Model):

```
name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)

number = models.IntegerField()

age = models.IntegerField()

is_captain = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

class Injuries(models.Model):

```
player = models.ForeignKey(Player, Player.name)

team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

Comment: the error is:                                                                                                                         teams.Injuries.player: (fields.E312) The to_field '<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000002899B25DB00>' doesn't exist on the related model 'teams.Player'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are my suggestions, as per my capability.

As per the documentation,

> A many-to-one relationship. Requires two positional arguments: the
>   class to which the model is related and the on_delete option.

See the reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey). So the first positional argument is the class which is related by Foreign Key and the second position argument is on_delete. You should define it as models.CASCADE or as appropriate for your app.
Thus in this case the second positional argument is "Player.name". I think you have to first replace it with models.CASCADE.

Thus change the code from what is below

```py
class Injuries(models.Model):

    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, Player.name)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

to the one below

```py
class Injuries(models.Model):

    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

The foreign key is set to the primary key of the related model. In this case (since you have not defined it), it will be player_id that is automatically assigned by django. If you want it to force it to use the "name" column from the Player model, then you have to set "unique=True" in the name field of the Player model. Also notice the use of to_field='name' option.

In such a case the changed code will be as below.

```py
class Player(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 256, unique=True)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    is_captain = models.BooleanField(default = False)

class Injuries(models.Model):

    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, to_field='name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

Hopefully it will work. If there is still an error, please let me know.

Comment: @zahir9 I think you will have to follow a similar approach to the team field in the Injuries model class. on_delete= .. have to be provided and to_field if needed. I am sorry, I did not pay attention to the team field. I was focussed on player field of the Injuries model since that was the source of error.